# How do I use tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I tried to use almost all examples and source code from internet and all of them just doesn't work. I got this warning "The type TabActivity is deprecated", anyone have source code for Tabhost that is really working and doesn't crash?

Comment: What's the `minSDK` version in your `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

Comment: Well, here's your problem, check out the Answers.

Comment: Use `Tablayout` from the new support library.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using Tabs anymore. Look after Fragments instead. a good place to start is
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html):

> **This class was deprecated in API level 13.**
>
> New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT.

You should learn [how to use Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead. TabHost/TabActivity isn't being actively supported any more, so if you're just learning how to do tabs, you should do it the new way. No point in learning something, only to have to replace it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From the link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html):

**This class was deprecated in API level 13.**
*New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT.*

So the suggestion is obvious - use Fragments. But don't ask here how, create a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

go through the link:http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/abstracting.html   Download the Sample App: TabCompat.zip